# could not open file base.csv

Tags: php, file, curl, file-upload

I am trying to send file in an api using `curl` in Yii 1. `File` us uploaded using a form and it is then sent to the `server` using api. This is what I am doing:

```
$apiFile= CUploadedFile::getInstanceByName('bases');
 $apiFile = new CURLFile($apiFile->name, $apiFile->type, $apiFile->tempName);
                    $postData = array(
                        'title' => $_POST['Bases']['title'],
                        'file' => $apiFile
                    );
```

And in the curl:

```
$ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        var_dump(curl_error($ch));
        curl_close($ch);
```

Now when code runs, it throws me this `error`:

> could not open file base.csv

My `php` version is `7.0.9` 
I have tried different solution mentioned here on SO but none of them seems to work. What am I ding wrong here? Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is error in CURLFile parameters order in your code example. It should be:
`$apiFile = new CURLFile($apiFile->tempName, $apiFile->type, $apiFile->name);`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

1) Check if your file path string has the extension of the file
2) Check if you're using absolute paths cause after PHP 5 CURLFile uses absolute paths.

Ref: https://recalll.co/ask/v/topic/php-curl%3A-%2826%29-couldn%27t-open-file/557990462bd2730c558ba7ea